# AWS Lambda function execution stops

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am executing a `lambda Nodejs function` that has following configuration:

**1) Max Memory : 512 Mb**

**2) Time out : 20 seconds**

Memory consumption for a single execution: **100 Mb**

It takes around **100 Mb** to execute a single function.

**What I noticed:**

When the `Lambda function` is executed multiple times, the memory consumed keeps on increasing from **100 Mb** to **128 Mb** to **155Mb** and so on ...

When it reaches the Max Memory (**512 Mb**), execution stops and I get the following error:

> Process exited before completing request

When tried after few minutes, the memory is cleaned up and it again sarts from **100 Mb**

Is there any way to clean up the used memory in Lambda function? If not, is there any other way to tackle this problem?

**EDIT:**

I am using this lambda function to generate image from `canvas` using `node-canvas`

Comment: Are you saving any data in `tmp` folder on each call?

Comment: No..I dont think I am, I am using this function to generate image from  node canvas

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have some static variables there. In Java environment, AWS-Lambda keeps the static variables in memory across multiple lambda executions. So If you have a static map and you add variables to it with each lambda execution, It stays in memory. This might be the case for node.js too.